# how to display text in textinput box when i press number button. i am creating passcode login

Tags: kivy

I am creating Passcode login app screen when i press button it will print text but not in textinput box. i want to print my text in text box which i created in my first screen. please help me.

**kivy**

```
    BT0 = Button(text="0", size_hint=(0.1, 0.1), pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}, color=(0, 0, 0, 1))
    BT0.bind(on_press=callback)
    layout.add_widget(BT0)

    

    textinput = TextInput(password=True,multiline=False, size_hint=(.2, .05), halign="center",
                          pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.8})

    textinput.bind()
    layout.add_widget(textinput)

    return layout
```

Comment: When you set `password=True`, the `TextInput` should show `*` characters instead of the typed text. Is that what you see?  Also, if your  `size_hint` is too small, the text may not show. Try increasing `size_hint_y` from `.05`.

Comment: My friend this topic about results flash in my text box when I press button it's print text and I want text display in my preferred location in application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you are trying to retrieve the text of a `TextInput` in another screen. All you have to do is give the `TextInput` an id, then you can simply grab the text by running `self.ids.NAME_OF_ID.text` (this must be within a class function)

Comment: That's use in .KV my code is in .PY

Comment: ```id = NAME_OF_ID```